# How to get Count of Distinct Columns Combination from within one table

Tags: sqlite, count, distinct

We have a table like this:

Columns

| tName | SourceWBS | MappedWBS |

Data

| F15 | 1.1.1.1 | 21-100A |

| F15 | 1.1.1.1 | 21-100B |

| F15 | 1.1.1.2 | 31-100A |

| F-15A | 1.1.1.2 | 31-100B |

What we are looking to try and get from this one table is the Count of the Distinct |tName|SourceWBS| Columns.

We are using this SQL:

```
Select DISTINCT [SourceWBS], [tName], Count(*) as [CountCN]
From [OurTable] 
Group By [SourceWBS], [tName];
```

Results:

| F15 | 1.1.1.1 | 2 |

| F15 | 1.1.1.2 | 1 |

| F-15A | 1.1.1.2 | 1 |

We are not including the [MappedWBS] column in the SELECT query and yet based on the first result record the Query appears to be including it.

Can this be done?

Appreciate any feed back.

Comment: The result is correct. What do you think is wrong? Why?

Comment: We don't think it is wrong. We were looking for advice on trying to get the results we were looking for hopefully using a single select query.

Comment: Where the first record result would be count of 1 rather than 2 (ignoring the [MappedWBS] field).

Comment: There are two rows with these name/sourceWBS values. Why should the result be one? What does that mean?

Comment: We recognize the outcome of the query provided is returning a count of 2 for the tname/sourcewbs in question. We have a requirement to get the count of each unique tname/sourcewbs combination from this one table. In terms of "unique" combinations of tname/sourcewbs field only -  there would only be a count of 1 for the tname/sourcewbs in question. Thanx. We will look for another avenue to satisfy this requirement from this table.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, "unique" means that the result should always be `1`. So just replace `Count(*)` with `1`.

Comment: Yeah, I think I probably confused you by not provided better information. The Count requirement is how many times a SourceWBS is found based on the Unique tName/SourceWBS combination. So for the example provided, SourceWBS (1.1.1.1) is found 1 time because it has the same tName each time. The F-15/1.1.1.1 combination is found once. There is no other fName/1.1.1.1 combination found, thus the number for SourceWBS (1.1.1.1) is 1. SourceWBS (1.1.1.2)  is found 2 times because it's associated tName field has a different value for each time found. And on and on with other combinations in this table.

Comment: Do you really need the `tName` column in the result?